# CSS selector, Match element that doesn't match given selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to match element that dose not match given selector using css.

Given the markup below, I'm trying to select only the first ".color"

```
<div uid="unique-id-1">
    <div>  <div class="color"></div> </div>
     <div uid="unique-id-2">
                 <div class="color"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I tried `[uid="unique-id-1"] .color:not([uid="unique-id-1"] [uid] .color)` which did not work obviously, but I think it will help to understand what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you improve your question? Seems you need a combination of :not() and nth-of-type() selectors.

Comment: yes, as @JoelHager asked, you need to be clear on your requirements, but as of now you can access your first color element like this in the given code, div[uid="unique-id-1"]:first-child .color {
        // your css
    }

Comment: @Atul thanks for the response, the selector you offered select both .color elements.

Comment: Why haven't you picked an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you're only going to apply the selector to this limited combination of elements (i.e. there aren't any other `.color`s in the page that could potentially be affected by this), then

```css
[uid="unique-id-1"] > div:not([uid]) > .color
```

Do consider renaming the attribute to `data-uid` if your application allows, so as to make it clearer that this is an app-specific and non-standard `uid` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

That seems simple:

```css
[uid="unique-id-1"]>:first-child .color {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div uid="unique-id-1">
  <div>
    <div class="color">A</div>
  </div>
  <div uid="unique-id-2">
    <div class="color">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That being said, `uid` as an attribute name makes your HTML invalid, so you should rename that to `data-uid`:

```css
[data-uid="unique-id-1"]>:first-child .color {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-uid="unique-id-1">
  <div>
    <div class="color">A</div>
  </div>
  <div data-uid="unique-id-2">
    <div class="color">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```